# Passing values between Windows form and a database

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I faced a problem while trying to build a Windows form solution for a college assignment, and hope somebody can point out my mistake.

The solution is about a mobile shop. I have two classes, Apple and Android forms. I need to read the data in the database table, categorize the entries to either Android or Apple phones, and then display all phones in a list when the form loads.

I can successfully categorize phones, but when trying to read the entries, I always end up with the same entry twice in my list on the form, while the second entry doesn't appear at all.

I know I made a big stupid mistake while doing the connection but I can't find it!.

Here is my code:

```
public abstract class MobilePhone {
    private Int32 phoneID;
    private string operatingSystem;
    private string make;
    private string model;
    public enum Condition { Poor, Fair, Good, Mint };
    private Condition condition;
    private decimal originalPrice;
    private DateTime datePurchase;
    private string description;
    private clsDataConnection dbConnection;

    //constructor
    public MobilePhone(string make, string model, decimal originalPrice, DateTime datePurchase, Condition condition, string description) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.originalPrice = originalPrice;
        this.datePurchase = datePurchase;
        this.condition = condition;
        this.description = description;
    }
```

Not complete, but that's what is relevant:

```
public class ApplePhone : MobilePhone {
    decimal ApproxValue;
    public ApplePhone(string make, string model, decimal originalPrice, DateTime datePurchase, Condition condition, string description)
        : base(make, model, originalPrice, datePurchase, condition, description) {
    }
```

The Android class is the same but with different other functions.

```
class Shop {
    clsDataConnection dbConnection;
    const int NotAdded = -1;  // invalid primary key
    private string name;
    private decimal ApproxValue;
    private Int32 phoneID;
    private string operatingSystem;
    private string make;
    private string model;
    private MobilePhone.Condition condition;
    private decimal originalPrice;
    private DateTime datePurchase;
    private string description;
    Int32 Index;
    private List<MobilePhone> phonesForSale;

    //constructor
    public Shop(string name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    MobilePhone phone;

    public void SelectAll() {
        dbConnection = new clsDataConnection();
        dbConnection.Execute("SellectAllPhones");
    }

    public void FilterByOperatingSystem(string operatingSystem) {
        dbConnection = new clsDataConnection();
        dbConnection.AddParameter("@OperatingSystem", operatingSystem);
        dbConnection.Execute("FilterByOperatingSystem");
    }

    public Int32 Count {
        get {
            //return the count of records
            return dbConnection.Count;
        }
    }

    public string DescribeCurrentPhone(int Index) {
        Int32 phoneID;
        string make;
        string model;
        MobilePhone.Condition condition;
        decimal originalPrice;
        DateTime datePurchase;
        string description;

        phoneID = Convert.ToInt32(phonesForSale[Index].PhoneID);
        make = Convert.ToString(phonesForSale[Index].Make);
        model = Convert.ToString(phonesForSale[Index].Model);
        condition = phonesForSale[Index].GetCondition;
        originalPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(phonesForSale[Index].OriginalPrice);
        datePurchase = Convert.ToDateTime(phonesForSale[Index].DatePurchased);
        description = Convert.ToString(phonesForSale[Index].Description);
        //set up a new object of class list item             
        string listItemText = make + " " + "|" + " " + model + " " + "|" + " " + condition + " " + "|" + " " + "£" + Math.Round(originalPrice, 2) + " " + "|" + " " + datePurchase.ToShortDateString() + " " + "|" + " " + description;
        return listItemText;
    }

    public List<MobilePhone> Allphones {
        get {
            phonesForSale = new List<MobilePhone>();
            int count = Count;
            Index = 0;
            while (Index < count) {
                phoneID = Convert.ToInt32(dbConnection.DataTable.Rows[Index]["PhoneId"]);
                operatingSystem = Convert.ToString(dbConnection.DataTable.Rows[Index]["OperatingSystem"]);
                make = Convert.ToString(dbConnection.DataTable.Rows[Index]["Make"]);
                model = Convert.ToString(dbConnection.DataTable.Rows[Index]["Model"]);
                string conditionString = Convert.ToString(dbConnection.DataTable.Rows[Index]["Condition"]);
                originalPrice = Convert.ToInt32(dbConnection.DataTable.Rows[Index]["OriginalPrice"]);
                datePurchase = Convert.ToDateTime(dbConnection.DataTable.Rows[Index]["DatePurchased"]);
                description = Convert.ToString(dbConnection.DataTable.Rows[Index]["Description"]);
                // Set Condition
                if (conditionString == "Poor") {
                    condition = MobilePhone.Condition.Poor;
                } else if (conditionString == "Fair") {
                    condition = MobilePhone.Condition.Fair;
                } else if (conditionString == "Good") {
                    condition = MobilePhone.Condition.Good;
                } else if (conditionString == "Mint") {
                    condition = MobilePhone.Condition.Mint;
                }
                //check Operating System
                if (operatingSystem == "IOS") {
                    phone = new ApplePhone(make, model, originalPrice, datePurchase, condition, description);
                    //ApproxValue = ApplePhone.CalculateApproximateValue();
                } else if (operatingSystem == "Android") {
                    phone = new AndroidPhone(make, model, originalPrice, datePurchase, condition, description);
                    //ApproxValue = AndroidPhone.CalculateApproximateValue();
                }
                Index++;
                phonesForSale.Add(phone);
            }
            return phonesForSale;
        }
    }
```

And the form code is:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form {
    public FormMain() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Shop shop = new Shop("");
    }

    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DisplayItems("");
    }

    protected int DisplayItems(string operatingSystem) {
        Shop MyShop = new Shop("");
        Int32 RecordCount;
        Int32 Index = 0;
        Int32 PID;

        if (operatingSystem != "") {
            MyShop.FilterByOperatingSystem(operatingSystem);
        } else {
            MyShop.SelectAll();
        }

        RecordCount = MyShop.Count;
        ArrayList MyPhones = new ArrayList();
        while (Index < RecordCount) {
            // I Suspect this line is the problem but don't know how to fix it
            PID = MyShop.Allphones[Index].PhoneID
            string listItemText = MyShop.DescribeCurrentPhone(PID);
            //add the new item to the list
            MyPhones.Add(listItemText);
            //increment the index
            Index++;
        }
        listBox1.DataSource = MyPhones;
        return RecordCount;
    }
```

I am not used to connecting to databases, so any advice will be of help!

Comment: 1st question. The method SelectAll(). what is this doing? It doesn't appear to return any data, it just calls dbConnection.Execute("SellectAllPhones")

Comment: it execute this stored procedure so that i can read it's resulted data (the table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of an alternative to the DB connection you have made is below

```
  List<MyPhone> myIPhoneList = new List<Myphone>();
   List<MyPhone> myAndroidList = new List<Myphone>();

SqlConnection myDBConnection = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString"); //DB Connection
            SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("SelectAllPhones"); //Stored Procedure
            SqlDataReader recordReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader(); //Execute

            //Read records return in to phone objects
            while (recordReader.Read()) {
                var phoneField1 = recordReader["PhoneField1FromDatabase"];
                var phoneField2 = recordReader["PhoneField2FromDatabase"];
                //etc...

                var myPhone = new MyPhone();
                myPhone.Name = phoneField1;
                //etc...
                if (myPhone.OS == "iPhone")
                 myIPhoneList.Add(myPhone);

               if (myPhone.OS = "Android")
                 myAndroidList.Add(myPhone);
            }
```

Comment: Create yourself 2 list of phones, 1 for each OS, then populate the contents of those lists to your form list

Comment: Also look at encapsulation. Your database connection should be in a separate class that returns your data back to ideally a business class which in turn would create and return the lists of phones back to your form.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found out that i don't need to use a database for this project so i will be fine for that one, but i will be using your advice on my other project to solve this problem so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a twist to Wheels answer really,

I'd personally put a filter on the stored-proc.

SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("SelectAllPhones"); //Stored Procedure

becomes something like:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectAllPhones", conn))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@OS", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = phoneOS });
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
      // load your data...

    }

  }
}
```

Only because there is very little point dragging both sets of phone data (android/iphone) for each class.  You may as well only pull back the data you require.

Of course the Stored-Proc will need an update to cater for the parameter.

something like:
AND PhoneOS = @OS

needs appending to your SQL condition.

clsDataConnection dbConnection; is unknown to me - is this a third party library or a class you've wrote and not included?

```
public Int32 Count
{
    get
    {
        //return the count of records
        return dbConnection.Count;
    }
}
```

dbConnection.Count seems very non-standard.  Doesn't read as if you're trying to get the number of rows, more the number of connections - which is invalid here.

dbConnection.DataTables[0].Rows.Count;  would be a better way of determining the rows using your existing code, as currently it reads as if your counting the number of database connections which isn't what your after - and would be redundant if using either mine or Wheels as you wont need to know beforehand how many rows your about to process.